# Virtualenv, where is it saved and how do i use it (python, windows 10)

Tags: python, windows-10, virtualenv

I have no idea how virtualenv works and need help. I have made a virtual environment, activated it, and so on but i dont know where it is saved, whether it is saved and how i can access it when i am making a python project. (by access i mean use it a project)

Comment: Read this article carefully - https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide.html.

Answer (score 0):

I use PyCharm Community Edition, there you can easily select if you want to create Virtual Environment and where to save it, all from GUI. The best IDE in my opinion as you can do everything using it's GUI, you can even search for and install libraries.

Comment: Is there a website that explains how?? (On PyCharm)Or is it very self explanatory

Comment: Very self explanatory, you download PyCharm, install it, open it, create new project, for python interpreter select venv (virtual environment), select where to create it. Done. There are probably guides and documentation on PyCharm website but I never searched for it, GUI is very easy to understand.